how to fix ApplePersistenceIgnoreState error?
I am following a neuralnine tutorial on how to do image classification with neural networks.
I am using an Imac.
Below is the code:
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tensorflow.keras import datasets, layers, models
#preparing data
(training_images, training_labels), (testing_images, testing_labels) = datasets.cifar10.load_data()
training_images, testing_images = training_images / 255, testing_images / 255

class_names = ['Plane', 'Car', 'Bird', 'Cat', 'Deer', 'Dog', 'Frog', 'Horse', 'Ship', 'Truck']


for i in range(16):
    plt.subplot(4,4,i+1)
    plt.xticks([])
    plt.yticks([])
    plt.imshow(training_images[i], cmap=plt.cm.binary)
    plt.xlabel(class_names[training_labels[i][0]])

plt.show()

training_images = training_images[:5000] #save time
training_labels = training_labels[:5000]
testing_images = testing_images[:4000]
testing_labels = testing_labels[:4000]

model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation='relu', input_shape=(32,32,3)))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(training_images, training_labels, epochs=10, validation_data=(testing_images, testing_labels))

I am geting the following message in my terminal:
ApplePersistenceIgnoreState: Existing state will not be touched. New state will be written to /var/folders/2g/.../T/org.python.python.savedState
2024-08-02 16:29:19.788 Python[48146:6869495] WARNING: Secure coding is not enabled for restorable state! Enable secure coding by implementing NSApplicationDelegate.applicationSupportsSecureRestorableState: and returning YES.

completely clueless as to what to do

You can ignore this ApplePersistenceIgnoreState warning from your system by turning off this unnecessary feature for Python by using below command in your Terminal:
defaults write org.python.python ApplePersistenceIgnoreState NO

Please have a look at this similar issue for your reference. Let us know if you are still facing this issue. Thank you
